# Define a racket function that duplicates the functionality of map

Tags: racket

Define your own Racket function that duplicates the the functionality of map from the standard library. You may not use the built-in map function as an auxiliary function.

Input: A function name (of a function that takes a single argument) and a list of elements of the same data type compatible with the function.

Output: A new list of the original elements with the same function applied to each. Example:

```
(my-map sqrt '(9 25 81 49))
```

> '(3 5 9 7)

```
(my-map double '(6 4 8 3))
```

> '(12 8 16 6)

```
(my-map sqr '(5 7))
```

> '(25 49)

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: SO users help other users when they're stuck with an approach. We're not here to do your homework problems!

Answer (score 1):

Read part three of HtDP version 2.

```
http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_three.html
```

In particular pay attention to section 17.1.

Some advice on starting this problem:

Write a function `map-sqrt` that takes a one argument, a list of numbers, as input and outputs a list of numbers (the square roots of the input numbers).

Write a function `map-sqr` that takes a one argument, a list of numbers, as input and outputs a list of numbers (the square of the input numbers).

These two functions are very similar. Use the approach in section 17.1 in order to see what a general map function looks like.